# Is there a way to get the file type of a document in an envelope (without extension)?

Tags: docusignapi

I am interesting in obtaining the file type (e.g. PDF, Word doc) of documents sent in an envelope. Of course this could be done just by getting the extension from the file name, but if a filename does not have an extension, is there an API call that would give me the file's type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. Once the document is uploaded to DocuSign, it's always converted into a PDF. The original is not stored anywhere. You can have code that uses custom fields to store this information, but other than that - you would have to use the file name and the extension in there.